# How to manually specify db connection for Quartz JobStoreTX

Tags: quartz-scheduler, ktor

I'm trying to configure Quartz in clustered mode in a Ktor application.
I want to avoid property file so I'm doing the scheduler initialization programmatically.
This is what I achieved so far:

```
val jobStore = JobStoreTX()
    jobStore.setIsClustered(true)
    jobStore.dataSource = "datasourceName" //Here is the issue - I want to inject datasource object, not the name
DirectSchedulerFactory.getInstance().createScheduler(
    "DS-SCHEDULER",
    "AUTO",
    SimpleThreadPool(),
    jobStore)
val scheduler = DirectSchedulerFactory.getInstance().getScheduler("DS-SCHEDULER")
scheduler.start()
```

I see that JobStoreTX class only allows to inject datasource name but I would like to provide a DataSource object because Ktor application does not have a naming service.
Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Please explain why do you need to pass a `DataSource` object instead of a `String`? You could use HOCON configuration to store data source string https://ktor.io/docs/configurations.html#read-configuration-in-code and then retrieve it when `JobStoreTX` is configured.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out how to solve.
So, given a datasource name "myDs", Quartz JobStoreSupport class will lookup for the datasource by name like this:

```
DBConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection(getDataSource())
```

where getDatasource() is an internal method that returns the datasource name string ("myDs").

So what I had to do was to manually add the connection provider to the DBConnectionManager before initializing the scheduler like this:

```
DBConnectionManager.getInstance().addConnectionProvider(
        "myDs",
        HikariCpPoolingConnectionProvider(
            "dbDriver",
            "dbUrl",
            "username",
            "password",
            10,
            "validation Query"
        )
    )
```

and then I can initalize the scheduler:

```
val jobStore = JobStoreTX()
    jobStore.setIsClustered(true)
    jobStore.dataSource = "myDs
    val simpleThreadPool = SimpleThreadPool()
    simpleThreadPool.threadCount = 5
    DirectSchedulerFactory.getInstance().createScheduler(
        "Scheduler Name,
        "AUTO",
        simpleThreadPool,
        jobStore
    )
```

Scheduler Factory is then able to lookup the datasource and getting DB connections.

Comment: I have a same requirement as urs, by refering this code I wrote below which is not working. I am getting org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Job : 'group2.jobA', because one already exists with this identification.

Comment: You manually created all quartz tables? Is there a way to add it through library?

Comment: Is there  no way in ktor to add the quartz.properties file?